# Refreshing datetimepicker in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, momentjs

I'm using http://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I'm i18ning my site. After selecting another language I'm also changing date using moment.js. Like this:

```
  $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
        $translate.use(key);
        moment.locale(key);

    };
```

And here's my problem: dates in calendar are changing after I use it for the first time (select date/change month etc).

It's probably because of refreshing it for the first time.

How can I manually refresh datetimepicker in the code? (ex: in the section i quote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest release you can fire an event to have it re-render.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I should have seen your question earlier! I'm glad it works for you.